# How to use xcb library in Python

Tags: 20.04, python

When I run `import xcb` I get error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xcb'
```

I installed packages python3-xcbgen and python3-xcffib, and tried to use python3, but it does not seem to be enough. (I didn't even find respective packages for older python version.)

Or should I use `import xcffib`, instead?